# Core Data fetchedObjects data = nil except for last entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I recently decided that my Core Data store was getting pretty messy so I decided to delete it. Searching on here I used the following code to delete my data

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest * allData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[allData setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TimeLineItem" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[allData setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

NSArray * datas = [context executeFetchRequest:allData error:&error];
//error handling goes here
for (NSManagedObject * data in datas) {
    [context deleteObject:data];
}
NSError *saveError = nil;
[context save:&saveError];
```

All well and good. I then commented out the delete code and turned on the following code to create a placeholder data in the store, and to see the data (in this case, that I just created)

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
TimeLineItem *timeLineItem = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TimeLineItem"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
timeLineItem.locationName = @"Test Bank2";
timeLineItem.date = [NSDate date];
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TimeLineItem"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (TimeLineItem *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"loc: %@", info.locationName);
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", info.date);
}
```

Still no issues. However upon the next run, assuming I'd left the dummy data entry lines in, only the last (newest dummy data just created) comes back as non-nil. See attached picture (pretend there were only 2 fetched objects instead of 6 as objects [0]-[3] are all the same as [4] - nil).

[nil fetched objects](http://inft.ly/3aP8bwF)

I've also looked directly at the sqlite database and the data all is fine:

[sqlite data view](http://inft.ly/vwicKux)

Can anyone shed light on what is happening to my data when it is read from the sqlite database on following launch?

Answer (score 0):

The `nil` properties that are irritating you are just displayed in the debugger because the details have not been fetched yet. If you iterate through your results and log specific properties, say, `locationName`, you will see it is all there.

Comment: When you say log specific properties, how does that differ from the NSLogs that I'm doing above?

Comment: That is because Core Data is always optimizing in the background. It will fetch the absolute minimum and fill in the blanks only when it is necessary. This is called [Faulting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html).